# Email to trigger PHP Script... Possible?

Tags: php, email, listserv

I'm in need of setting up an auto-response from an email account that I control, based on `trigger words` within the body of the email.  But also, it needs to add/delete rows from a database table based on trigger words sent to this email account (that belongs to my site) and it needs to create a topic, in some cases, within a forum, if sent to a different email address (but on the same server).  I know PHP to be able to do this, but not really sure how to trigger a PHP script to be executed when an email gets sent to a specific email address account that I control.  Or if there is another solution to accomplish this, please let me know.

This is basically an inquiry on how to accomplish something like this, based on an email sent to a specific email address on my server with words like:  "Join", "Leave", "Set Mail", "Set Digest", etc. etc.

There will be another email address account set aside that will need to send those subscribers in the database, the same exact email (Mass Send).  This is for a CDB-L ListServ.  Kind of old school I suppose, but we want to transfer this ability to our server, since these old school methods still work today and is very much active.

Curious on security issues, what type of server software I'll need and just a basic approach on how to set something like this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alias your email address directly to a php script if you run your own mail server (on linux this would just be in the /etc/alias file or equivalent where the target was your php script instead of an email address) eg http://www.topwebhosts.org/bbs/board.php?bo_table=server_mgmt&wr_id=73

If not, then your only real choice is to set up a php process that checks an email address for mail every x minutes.

I have used both these methods over the years to great success

Comment: Not sure if I have the ability to access the mail server directly... will look into this though.  Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot directly access the server, all you can do is use php to collect email from the email address, there are several functions or libraries you can use to do that depending on what methods your server supports, POP or IMAP etc

Comment: Well, my main concern would be how to filter out SPAM and junk emails, if they get sent to that email address?

Comment: Sounds like your script will look for specific commands. If the spams do not contain those commands then your script can just ignore them

Comment: Well yeah, sounds pretty secure I suppose... But what if the spam does contain those commands?  For example, wouldn't want a spam containing a word like "Join" in it, cause then they would be able to spam everyone on the list in that case.  Anyway to check for spam?

Comment: There is no reliable way to check for spam. especially if you cant set up spam filters on the server. You can try searching for a third party spam filtering service, but if you are expecting an email with just join in it, then why would you process an email that says why not join us now for great discounts ...... You shoudl also send a confirmation email that requires them to click a link to confirm joining this will never get to most spammers who dont use thier own email address to send spam

Comment: Ok, thanks, didn't think of that.  Will definitely set it up like this.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can walk through emails with PHP's `IMAP` functions and undertake action (based on conditions/content). More [info](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php).